# How can I find a cameras sensor size in matlab

Tags: matlab, camera, webcam, matlab-cvst

I am doing a university project using mat-lab and a webcam.
My equations require the knowledge of my camera's sensor size, is there any way to calculate this value in mat-lab?
I am stuck with problem for four days any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you not know the make/model of webcam? Seems like the sort of thing that should be in the specs.

Comment: My project uses the laptops webcam and these specs are not available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate image sensor size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666618/calculate-image-sensor-size)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find what you need for your equation by extracting the camera parameters. They are some nice implemented functions in matlab to do so.

You can use some functions directly after taking several pictures of a checkerboard with your webcam
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/geometric-camera-calibration.html

or the app
http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/camera-calibration-with-matlab-81233.html

Answer (score 0):

most images contains a meta-data structure called EXIF. [Learn more about EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).
Generally the EXIF structure contains all sensor and image related information: sensor-size, ...

To extract the EXIF structure from an image using Matlab use the exifread function, which returns all EXIF tags.

```
output = exifread(filename)
```

Then process it to extract the sensor size.

[Learn more about exifread function](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exifread.html)

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the 'exifread' function does not provide any info about the camera it returns the info of the image only

Comment: Are you sure that your images contain EXIF sensor information?

Comment: yes but the function did not return the sensor size value